# Overwrite and call collection

Tags: collection, magento-1

I want to extend `Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Shipment_Item_Collection` because it doesn't come with a `getIntervals()` function.

So I created following files:

**MyModule/Modulename/Model/Mysql4/Shipping/Collection:**

```
class MyModule_Modulename_Model_Mysql4_Shipping_Collection 
extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract {

public function _construct() {
    parent::_construct();
    $this->_init('sales/order_shipment_item_collection');
}
```

**MyModule/Modulename/etc/config.xml**

```
<global>
    <models>
        <modulename>
            <class>MyModule_Modulename_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>modulename_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </modulename>
        <modulename_mysql4>
            <class>MyModule_Modulename_Model_Mysql4</class>
        </modulename_mysql4>
    </models>
</global>
```

In my order grid I want to call the collection with

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('modulename/mymodule_modulename_shipping_collection');
```

But the collection is empty and I can't figure out why. Can anyone point me in the right direction, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to extend `Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Shipment_Item_Collection`

But you didn't. You extended `Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract`. The `_init()` parameter is used to determine the model which belongs to the collection, you cannot use it to extend another collection.

So change the class to

```
class MyModule_Modulename_Model_Mysql4_Shipping_Collection extends Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Shipment_Item_Collection
{
    // add your getInterval() method here
}
```